# The output of linux command uptime is different from that of command nmap

Tags: linux, nmap

In my linux box the command uptime tells me 800 days. However the command nmap says 48 days (in the Uptime line of its output). Should these 2 UPTIMEs be same? If not what each really means?

Comment: The documentation about "uptime guess" at http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html should answer this.

Comment: So, based on the help posted, the answer could look like:

No, those 2 UPTIMEs don't have to be the same. The former reports the actual uptime of the host; while the latter provides just a guess.

Right?

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason why `nmap` prints `Uptime guess`. `nmap` detects the uptime by sending multiple consecutive `SYN/ACK TCP` and checks if there is timestamps option or a counter value, etc. Also the incremental rate may vary from `OS` to `OS`. Finally, some `OS`-es start the counter with a random value which complicates the uptime detection algorithm.

Best is to go and read the documentation on the topic on `nmap`'s webpage: [Nmap: Remote OS Detection](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-usage.html)

Comment: So if I just want to know the actual uptime of my host, I can trust the command "uptime", and ignore what nmap tells me, right?

Comment: @GoldThumb Yes, ``nmap``'s OS detection option does not provide certain results. It only makes educated guesses.

Comment: Sorry before I dive into nmap's doc, could you tell me why 48 days is an "educated guess" when the actual value is 800 days :-D

Comment: Is it possible that my host was hacked?

Comment: @GoldThumb The documentation on uptime is only 10 lines and explains everything you need to know. However, I will try to explain here: Your Linux OS has access to all the required information to calculate that value, while ``nmap`` gathers information from its exchange of packets with the host. The information it gathers is evaluated on a group of factors (such as timestamps, counter, etc). If one or more of these values is randomized by your host and does not behave as expected, ``nmap`` will not be able to make as good guess as before.

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with that if your host is hacked or not, and should not be used as an indicator of such thing.